# Spree - cannot override js.coffee file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, overriding, spree

Simply followed instructions from http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/asset.html but it just doesn't work. New js files are included and loaded, but if I create file with the same name say product.js.coffee original file is loaded anyway. Any suggestions?

All.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require spree/frontend
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been tearing my hair out over this problem all morning.

In the end what worked for me is to specify every single file I wanted to overwrite in `/app/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js`.

E.g., if you want to overwrite `cart.js.coffee` and `checkout/address.js.coffee`, your `all.js` should look like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//
//= require spree/frontend
//= require spree/frontend/cart
//= require spree/frontend/checkout/address
//
//= require_tree .
```

Don't ask me why that's necessary. My understanding is that `//= require_tree .` should do that automatically, but it my case, well, it wasn't.

After creating an `all.js` file and redundantly specifying each file, this finally worked for me. But I'm a spree/rails noob, so there's quite probably a better solution.

### Edit:

Actually, to get this working I had to put the above in `/vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js` and remove `/app/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js`. Still confused why this is necessary and why `require_tree` doesn't pick these up automatically, but happy to finally get it working.

Comment: In my scenario, I was trying to overwrite `app/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/flash.coffee` in Solidus. 
 Defining `vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/flash.coffee` in my project and adding `//= require spree/backend/flash` to `vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js` did not overwrite the original JS code, it only added the new JS code. To remove the old JS code, had to also override the `//= require spree/backend` call by defining `vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend.js` in my project.

Answer (score 1):

[Backporting this patch for Solidus 2.1.0](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/pull/1613) solved my issue of replacing/overwriting JS assets [1].

The problem appeared to be that there was an issue with Sprockets where using `require_tree` or relative `require` prevented JS assets in the pipeline from being overridden.

In summary

1. Create a new file under your project's vendor/assets with the same filename as the JS file you're going to replace in Solidus. For example, to overwrite the file `solidus_backend/app/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/flash.coffee`, create a replacement file in your project at `your_project/{app,vendor}/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/flash.coffee`. [2]
2. Create the files `your_project/{app,vendor}/assets/javascripts/spree/backend.js` and `your_project/{app,vendor}/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/templates/index.js` in your project.
3. Copy the contents for the `backend.js` and `index.js` files from [solidusio/solidus#1613](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/pull/1613/files) into your project.
4. Remove any requires for files that do not exist in your Solidus version, and keep any custom requires if you already had `backend.js` and `index.js` defined. [3]

---

Footnotes

1. Includes .js, .coffee, .hbs, and any other files that compile to JavaScript during the asset pipeline compilation.
2. Either directory between `{app,vendor}/assets` in your project will work since they should both be in the asset pipeline loadpath. It's a matter of preference how you want to organise Solidus extensions and overrides.
3. I had to remove `spree/backend/images/upload` from `backend.js`
   and `spree/backend/templates/products/upload_progress` from `index.js` since I was using an older version of Solidus and those files didn't exist yet, so I would get an FileNotFound error from Sprockets.